# How good will InnoDB handles select statment with multi join opporations on a large database?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am working on designing a large database for a heavy used application. The application will have many insets/updates going on it at the sale time but I will have a lot more Selects. I will be doing a lot of select statements with multi (3-6) inner joins involved.

How will innoDB handles these complex select statement. I will also be using lots of datetime clause in my select as a filter.

So for such an application is it will InnoDB be a better choice over MyIsam? Or should I stick or the old MyIsam method?

This is an example of a select statement

```
    SELECT act.subject, act.attempts, in.industry_name, zn.zone_name, cc.code_id, DATE_FORMAT(act.due_on, "%m-%d-%Y %T") AS due_on FROM activities AS act
    INNER JOIN industries AS in ON in.industry_id = act.industry_id
    INNER JOIN zones AS zn ON zn.zone_id = act.zone_id
    INNER JOIN call_codes AS cc ON cc.code_id = act.code_id
    WHERE act.due_on BETWEEN (CURRDATE() + ' 00:00:00')  AND (CURRDATE() + ' 23:59:59')
    ORDER BY act.due_on

**This is a summery of fields description**
The following field's  type are CHAR(50)
act.subject
in.industry_name
zn.zone_name

the following field's type are INT(10) unsigned and they are all foreign keys
cc.code_id
in.industry_id
zn.zone_id

the following field's type are INT(10) unsigned and they all are indexed
act.industry_id
act.zone_id
act.code_id


this field is a date time
act.due_on
```

I should also note that my activities table has 3 million records. Also I will be doing heavy reports using COUNT(), MAX(), MIX(), SUM(), AVG(), CASE WHEN SOME THEN OTHER END.....

Comment: Depends what you have as your primary, any foreign keys? too little to little imformation to say. Why not unit test your application before deciding?

Comment: Please check my post again as I added more details on a sample of one query that will be used very frequently in my application. it will be one of the primary select statement.

Comment: are you using a server-side like php?

Comment: Yes I am using PHP/MySql